# Format date with random number of split seconds

Tags: java, date, date-conversion

I need to parse a string to date. The problem is that the string has a random number of split seconds. To be more precise the number of digits vary between 0 and 7. To test this i wrote the following scenario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // printDate("2016-02-10T12:48:08.632746Z");
    printDate("2016-02-10T12:48:08.632Z");

}

private static void printDate(String datumAsString) throws ParseException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(datumAsString, formatter));
}
```

The commented line does not work (it throws a ParseException). Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can't have more than 3 digit _millis_ - it's alreay in the name: 1/1000th of a second, which is at most a 3 digit number.

Comment: @Chris311 how can millisecond have more than 3 digits when max it can have is 999. Anyway using a single 'S' instead of 'SSS' would solve the problem.

Comment: For more clarity, can you quote some sample entries of the string (with random number of millis) ?

Comment: "does not work" doesn't tell us what you're seeing... please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the digits after the seconds represent a fraction of second and not a number of milliseconds, both strings can be parse "natively" by `ZonedDateTime` - so you could write:

```
private static void printDate(String datumAsString) throws ParseException {
  LocalDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datumAsString).toLocalDateTime(); 
  System.out.println(ldt);
}
```

You may also want to stick with a `ZonedDateTime` instead of ignoring the time zone information.

Comment: To explain, this correct Answer works because the input String is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes parse/generate ISO 8601 compliant strings by default. So no need to specify a formatter.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to force your function to trim off all extra numbers after the given length.

Obviously if you do not need the extended precision.

For Example,

```
String datumAsString = "2016-02-10T12:48:08.632746Z";

int position = datumAsString.lastIndexOf(".");      

String head = datumAsString.substring(0,position);
String tail = datumAsString.substring(position);
String trimmedDate = null;

if(tail.length() > 5) {
    trimmedDate = head + tail.substring(0,4) + "Z";
} else {
    char[] chr = new char[5 - tail.length()];
    Arrays.fill(chr, '0');
    trimmedDate = head + tail.substring(0, tail.length() - 1) + new String(chr) + "Z";
}

System.out.println(trimmedDate);
```

Output:

```
2016-02-10T12:48:08.632Z
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
private static void printDate(String datumAsString) throws ParseException {
    DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

    /* Set Milliseconds Precision (3) */
    int position = datumAsString.lastIndexOf(".");      
    String head = datumAsString.substring(0,position);
    String tail = datumAsString.substring(position);
    String trimmedDate = null;
    if(tail.length() > 5) {
        trimmedDate = head + tail.substring(0,4) + "Z";
    } else {
        char[] chr = new char[5 - tail.length()];
        Arrays.fill(chr, '0');
        trimmedDate = head + tail.substring(0, tail.length() - 1) + new String(chr) + "Z";
    }

    /* Format Date */
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(trimmedDate, ft));
}
```

Comment: I don't want to manipulate the date. I want to persist it as it comes.